# What is sent to the llm when using a chat model?

Tags: nlp, langchain

I am confused by how multiple messages are combined and sent to a large language model such as `ChatOpenAI`.

```
from langchain_core.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate

template = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages([
    ("system", "You are a helpful AI bot. Your name is {name}."),
    ("human", "Hello, how are you doing?"),
    ("ai", "I'm doing well, thanks!"),
    ("human", "{user_input}"),
])

messages = template.format_messages(
    name="Bob",
    user_input="What is your name?"
)

messages
```

```
[SystemMessage(content='You are a helpful AI bot. Your name is Bob.'),
 HumanMessage(content='Hello, how are you doing?'),
 AIMessage(content="I'm doing well, thanks!"),
 HumanMessage(content='What is your name?')]
```

Is it generating text that looks like this:

```
System:
Human:
Assistant:
Human:
...
```

How can I print the final text sent to the llm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `format` method to format the chat template into a string, here is the updated code:

```py
prompt = template.format(
    name="Bob",
    user_input="What is your name?"
)

prompt
```

Output:

```
System: You are a helpful AI bot. Your name is Bob.
Human: Hello, how are you doing?
AI: I'm doing well, thanks!
Human: What is your name?
```

Comment: The OpenAI API works with an array of messages (in JSON). [docs](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/chat/create) Is there a chance they are doing something different than what `template.format` outputs?

Answer (score 0):

One of the options to do that

```py
import pprint
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=0)
pp.pprint(messages)
```